# Want to display the special price directly with out any pop dailog box?

Tags: magento-2.1, list.phtml

[image]

hi

I dont want this dailog box and i want to show the price in the place of Click for price.

Comment: include your `list.phtml` code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can See `Special price` is entered at wrong place i.e it is place in `MAP/MSRP` section.

Please edit product and remove price form:

**MSRP(Manufacturer's Suggested Retail Price)/MAP (Minimum Advertised Price)**

and add to

**Special price**

Please see attached image:

[image]

Comment: Welcome Dattatraya :)